# google maps android studio does not show my polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-polyline

I don't know why this polyline won't show, I already put the google maps api and enabled the directions api as well

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();

    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(24.009115, -104.699933));
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(24.009115, -104.699933));
    rectOptions.width(5);
    rectOptions.color(Color.RED);  

   Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Add()`, `width()` and `color()` all return a `PolylineOptions` with the new settings added.

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();

rectOptions =rectOptions.add(new LatLng(24.009115, -104.699933));
rectOptions =rectOptions.add(new LatLng(24.009115, -104.699933));
rectOptions =rectOptions.width(5);
rectOptions =rectOptions.color(Color.RED);  
Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

or

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
.add(new LatLng(24.009115,-104.699933),
new latlang(24.009115,-104.699933))
.width(5)
.color(Color.red);
Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Source:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions